# Google Play Store Incompatible for Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I recently released my Flutter app on the Google Play Store. I'm new to Android and bought a BLU Advance to test out the app. The app successfully published for Beta testing and I was able to set up my phone and Google Play Store profile, but I'm receiving the error that my app is not compatible. See here:

[image: Screenshot of Playstore]

Is it typical for apps not to work for all phones? How do I best make my app so that it's accessible to all (or as many as possible) Android devices?

Comment: 1) Were you able to install your app on the BLU Advance previous? 2) Did you delete all development/test versions of the app before trying to install from the Google Play Beta channel? 3) What is the minimum SDK level of your app?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: I accidentally had my minimum SDK version the same as the target SDK version. Lowered the min to 21 and solved this.